# How can I get the XML-part between "quotation marks" in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xliff

I am writing a program in C#, to convert XML(XLF) to JSON.

```
<group id="THISisWHATiWANT">
    <trans-unit id="loadingDocument" translate="yes" xml:space="preserve">
                <source>Harry</source>
                <target state="final">Potter1</target>
            </trans-unit>
  </group>
```

How can I get the group id?

---

This is what I already have:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml);
```

Comment: @nvoigt I didn't know that this is called "attribute value" so I couldn't find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is an *attribute* value.

I'd strongly suggest using LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) rather than `XmlDocument` - it's a much more modern API. In this case, you could use:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string groupId = doc.Root.Attribute("id").Value;
```

If this is actually part of a larger document, you might use something like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XElement group = doc.Descendants("group").First();
string groupId = group.Attribute("id").Value;
```